# I want to Write a Single Method for all the Following Http Calls in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

**Code:-**

```
AddressBook.service('AddressBookServices', ['$http', function ($http)
{

    this.GetAll = function ()
    {
        return $http.get('api/contacts');
    };
    this.EditContact = function (newContact)
    {
        return $http.put('api/contacts', newContact);
    };
    this.AddContact=function(newContact)
    {
        return $http.post('api/contacts', newContact);
    };
    this.DeleteContact=function(Id)
    {
        return $http.delete('api/contacts', Id);
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea is to use a resource instead of http. Resource will give a very good high level abstraction on the operations it will perform.

Answer (score 0):

```
AddressBook.service('AddressBookServices', ['$http', function ($http)
 {
this.ContactService = function (data, method) {
    url = 'api/contacts';
    if (method == 'delete') {
        url += '/' + data;
        data = "";
    }
    var req = {
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
    }
  return  $http(req);
};
```

And use the following syntax to call the Generic method

```
AddressBookServices.ContactService("sampledata","get");
```